# What should be done to enable foreign chars?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, python-2.7

I'm looking for a way to enable foreign chars in my reporting output. The output is HTML that I convert to PDF to make appengine send a PDF email. The output can't handle int. chars eg. åäö:
[image]

The code that makes the report is

```
class Report(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        # Create a conversion request from HTML to PDF.
        users = User.query()
        today = date.today()
        startdate = date(today.year, today.month, 1) # first day of month   
        html = None     
        for user in users: 
            if user.activity() > 0:
                logging.info('found active user %s %s' % (user.firstname, user.lastname))
                html = '<html><body><table border="1">'
                level = user.level()
                distributor = user
                while distributor.has_downline():
                    downline = User.query(User.sponsor == distributor.key).order(User.lastname).fetch()
                    for person in downline:  # to this for whole downline
                        orders = model.Order.all().filter('distributor_id =' , person.key.id()).filter('created >' , startdate).filter('status =', 'PAID').fetch(999999)
                        silver = 0
                        name = person.firstname +' '+ person.lastname
                        for order in orders:
                            logging.info('found orders')
                            for idx,item in enumerate(order.items):
                                purchase = model.Item.get_by_id(long(item.id()))
                                amount = int(order.amounts[idx])
                                silver = silver + amount*purchase.silver/1000.000 
                            if len(name) > 13:
                                name = name[13]
                            html = html + '<tr><td>' + str(order.created.date().day)+'/'+ str(order.created.date().month )+'</td><td>' + filters.makeid(person.key.id()) +'</td><td>' + name + '</td><td>' + str(order.key().id()) + '</td><td>' + str(silver) 
                            dist_level = order.dist_level
                            bonus = 0   
                            if level == 5 and dist_level == 4:                          
                                bonus = 0.05
                            if level == 5 and dist_level == 3:
                                bonus = 0.1
                            if level == 5 and dist_level == 2:
                                bonus = 0.13
                            if level == 5 and dist_level == 1:
                                bonus = 0.35

                            if level == 4 and dist_level == 3:                          
                                bonus = 0.05
                            if level == 4 and dist_level == 2:
                                bonus = 0.08
                            if level == 4 and dist_level == 1:
                                bonus = 0.3

                            if level == 3 and dist_level == 2:                          
                                bonus = 0.03
                            if level == 3 and dist_level == 1:
                                bonus = 0.25

                            if level == 2 and dist_level == 1:                          
                                bonus = 0.2

                            html = html + '</td><td>' + str(bonus) + '</td><td>' + str(order.total)
                            bonusmoney = bonus * float(order.total)
                            html = html + '</td><td>' + str(bonusmoney) + '</td></tr>'

                        distributor = person

                html = html + '</table>'

            asset = conversion.Asset("text/html", html, "test.html")
            conversion_obj = conversion.Conversion(asset, "application/pdf")        
            rpc = conversion.create_rpc()
            conversion.make_convert_call(rpc, conversion_obj)

            result = rpc.get_result()
            if result.assets:
                for asset in result.assets:
                    logging.info('emailing report')# to %s' % user.email)
                    message = mail.EmailMessage(sender='noreply@bnano.se',
                                    subject='Report %s %s' % (user.firstname, user.lastname))
                    message.body = 'Here is the monthly report'
                    message.to = 'niklasro@gmail.com'
                    message.bcc = 'fridge@koolbusiness.com'
                    message.attachments = ['report.pdf', asset.data]
                    message.send()
                    logging.info('message sent')
```

What should be done to enable foreign chars in this case?
Thanks

Comment: must, resist, the urge, to clean the code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `<head>` to the `html = '<html><body><table border="1">'`,
This should contain meta tag:
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`

If utf-8 charset won't help, maybe some iso-8859-x will.

Answer (score 3):

The two Holy Rules for Unicode programming:

- Be *certain* of what encoding your input has, and decode it appropriately.
- Be *explicit* of what encoding your output has.

Your code appears to rely on User.query decoding the input (otherwise your sorting won't work!), but it doesn't do anything about the second point.  Do the following:

- Assure that the person.firstname fields are indeed Unicode strings.  If you need to inspect the contents, look at the hexadecimal representation of each character; just printing the string out causes some automatic encoding and hides the source representation.  If they aren't Unicode strings, *fix User.query*.
- Explicitly *encode* your output as UTF-8, and *explicitly* mark the output as UTF-8 encoded (do as grodzik suggested - that should work).

Just adding a encoding=UTF8 mark to the output *may* give the correct end result, but that is purely by accident if you don't have control of the intermediate data.  (You will also notice that your sorting will be off.)

Comment: You should also set the `Content-Type` HTTP header to `text/html;charset=utf-8`, assuming that `utf-8` is the chosen output encoding.

Answer (score 1):

it looks as though it's handling them, but the encoding is wrong. you might need to do something like name.decode('utf-8').encode('latin-1')

of course, I'm only guessing at the encodings.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I will look at these encodings to see which is working for my data.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar experience with my code. My native language is Icelandic so we tend to have a lot of non English characters in our data.  This particular time I have made my due diligence on all fronts except making sure the .py file it self was encoded as utf-8 and not ansi, which for some reasons created unpredictable results.

So if all else fails, check your document encoding and make sure it's set to utf-8.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check the [htmllib.htmlentitydefs](http://docs.python.org/library/htmllib.html#module-htmlentitydefs) module. And don't forget to declare encoding in your input forms and pages to ensure all data is encoded uniformly or, at least, always be aware of it and act accordingly.